# Facing issue while using log4j for DB logging

Tags: logging, log4j

I am using Log4j for logging into database. I am inserting records into 2 different tables which have parent child relationship. DB tables have constraint on them that unless and until a record inserted in parent table, there cant be child record in another table with for that parent.

But when my application run & start logging into DB, log4j does this logging asynchronously & it doesn't maintain the priority for logging. Hence it end up in inserting record in child table first, which result in error.

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this error or set priority for the insert statements?

Comment: Can you add your log4j configuration?

Comment: # Define the file appender
log4j.appender.auditlog=INFO
log4j.appender.auditlog=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender
log4j.appender.auditlog.URL=jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXXXXXXX:1521/XXXXXX
log4j.appender.auditlog.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
log4j.appender.auditlog.user=XXXXXX
log4j.appender.auditlog.password=XXXXX
log4j.appender.auditlog.sql=insert into parent_table 
log4j.appender.auditlog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.auditlog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}

Comment: log4j.appender.auditdetail=INFO
log4j.appender.auditdetail=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender
log4j.appender.auditdetail.URL=jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXXXXXX:1521/XXXXXXX
log4j.appender.auditdetail.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
log4j.appender.auditdetail.user=XXXXXXX
log4j.appender.auditdetail.password=XXXXXXX
log4j.appender.auditdetail.sql=insert into child_table 
log4j.appender.auditdetail.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.auditdetail.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}